# Failed to extract array data so inside of the loop body

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I need to loop through a multidimensional array and extract all the data:

PHP code:

```php
//Loads the data and transforms it into an array
$json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'));

//Loops through the array and returns the values
echo '<br>'.'Modal: ' .$json_data->list[0]->mode;
echo '<br>'.'Variation: ' .$json_data->list[0]->change;
foreach ($json_data->list[0]->expiry as $data) {
        echo '<br>'.'Due date: ' .$data->cdexpiry;
        echo '<br>'.'Value: ' .$data->vlexpiry;
}
```

JSON data:

```json
{
    "list": [
        {
            "expiry": [
                {
                    "cdexpiry": "v130",
                    "vlexpiry": "33528.99"
                },
                {
                    "cdexpiry": "v230",
                    "vlexpiry": "21648.39"
                },
                {
                    "cdexpiry": "v150",
                    "vlexpiry": "185350.30"
                }
            ],
            "mode": "0401",
            "change": "N"
        },
        {
            "expiry": {
                "cdexpiry": "v40",
                "vlexpiry": "1091.46"
            },
            "mode": "1904",
            "change": "N"
        },
        {
            "expiry": {
                "cdexpiry": "v770",
                "vlexpiry": "1001.56"
            },
            "mode": "1904",
            "change": "N"
        },
        {
            "expiry": [
                {
                    "cdexpiry": "v130",
                    "vlexpiry": "2084.08"
                },
                {
                    "cdexpiry": "v260",
                    "vlexpiry": "28362.31"
                }
            ],
            "mode": "0213",
            "change": "N"
        },
        {
            "expiry": {
                "cdexpiry": "v210",
                "vlexpiry": "296.78"
            },
            "mode": "0101",
            "change": "N"
        },
        {
            "expiry": [
                {
                    "cdexpiry": "v245",
                    "vlexpiry": "1495.37"
                },
                {
                    "cdexpiry": "v248",
                    "vlexpiry": "1440.37"
                }
            ],
            "mode": "0217",
            "change": "N"
        }
    ],
    "type": "8"
}
```

I've used a few for's and if's - but I'm missing something.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($json_data->list); $i++) {
if(isset($json_data->list[$i]->expiry))
```

**Desired Outcome**

| **Type** | Value |
| --- | --- |
| **Modal** | **0401** |
| **Variation** | **N** |
| Due date | v130 |
| Value | 33528.99 |
| Due date | v230 |
| Value | 21648.39 |
| Due date | v150 |
| Value | 185350.30 |
| **---** | **---** |
| **Modal** | **1904** |
| **Variation** | **N** |
| Due date | V40 |
| Value | 1091.46 |
| Due date | v770 |
| Value | 1001.56 |
| **---** | **---** |
| **Modal** | **0213** |
| **Variation** | **N** |
| Due date | v130 |
| Value | 2084.08 |
| Due date | v260 |
| Value | 28362.31 |
| **---** | **---** |
| **Modal** | **0101** |
| **Variation** | **N** |
| Due date | V210 |
| Value | 296.78 |
| **---** | **---** |
| **Modal** | **0217** |
| **Variation** | **N** |
| Due date | V245 |
| Value | 1495.37 |
| Due date | V248 |
| Value | 1440.37 |

---

### This is the original XML query return file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1odW2Ctt5d3Z_07VoWkiE2_ltscP7_vRi/view?usp=sharing)

I need to extract all the data from the array to be able to manipulate it later. I count on the masters' help!

Comment: You forgot to say what your actual, specific problem is ...

Comment: yes I did, I can't go through the foreach loop inside the array, and with that I can't extract the data to be processed. 

if foreach tries to access the list[1] pointer object, it returns an error.

The foreach function can only load data from array 0 and 5...

Comment: And _what_ error would that be?

Comment: That JSON has an irregular structure. Sure that is the actual data you receive? `expiry` is sometimes an array, sometimes an object. Very strange.

Comment: yep I agree, and this is taking my sleep away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have an inconsistent array structure, so not only do need to write loops to access each layer, you need to write a condition to accommodate the deviated subset structures.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/k78AU) click the eye icon to render the html output)

```
$json_data = json_decode($json);
echo "<table border=1>\n";
    echo "\t<tr><td>Type</td><td>Value</td></tr>\n";
    foreach ($json_data->list as $list) {
        echo "\t<tr><td>Modal</td><td>{$list->mode}</td></tr>\n";
        echo "\t<tr><td>Variation</td><td>{$list->change}</td></tr>\n";
        foreach ($list as $key => $data) {
            if ($key === 'expiry') {
                if (is_array($data)) {
                    foreach ($data as $prop) {
                        echo "\t<tr><td>Due date</td><td>$prop->cdexpiry</td></tr>\n";
                        echo "\t<tr><td>Value</td><td>$prop->vlexpiry</td></tr>\n";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "\t<tr><td>Due date</td><td>$data->cdexpiry</td></tr>\n";
                    echo "\t<tr><td>Value</td><td>$data->vlexpiry</td></tr>\n";
                }
            }
        }
        echo "\t<tr><td>---</td><td>---</td></tr>\n";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: – Basic your insight/logic – helped me a lot. Tks!

Answer (score 0):

That JSON has an irregular structure. Sure that is the actual data you receive? expiry is sometimes an array, sometimes an object. Very strange.

Take a look at this example to understand how to traverse it:

```
<?php
$json = <<<JSON
{"list":[{"expiry":[{"cdexpiry":"v130","vlexpiry":"33528.99"},{"cdexpiry":"v230","vlexpiry":"21648.39"},{"cdexpiry":"v150","vlexpiry":"185350.30"},{"cdexpiry":"v120","vlexpiry":"33904.03"},{"cdexpiry":"v175","vlexpiry":"47796.73"},{"cdexpiry":"v220","vlexpiry":"21258.62"},{"cdexpiry":"v170","vlexpiry":"261294.42"},{"cdexpiry":"v140","vlexpiry":"98363.25"},{"cdexpiry":"v110","vlexpiry":"30818.43"},{"cdexpiry":"v165","vlexpiry":"298457.07"},{"cdexpiry":"v240","vlexpiry":"13807.67"},{"cdexpiry":"v210","vlexpiry":"10761.00"},{"cdexpiry":"v160","vlexpiry":"321684.92"}],"mode":"0401","change":"N"},{"expiry":{"cdexpiry":"v210","vlexpiry":"3501.37"},"mode":"0204","change":"N"},{"expiry":{"cdexpiry":"v40","vlexpiry":"1091.46"},"mode":"1904","change":"N"},{"expiry":[{"cdexpiry":"v130","vlexpiry":"2084.08"},{"cdexpiry":"v260","vlexpiry":"28362.31"},{"cdexpiry":"v230","vlexpiry":"823.44"},{"cdexpiry":"v150","vlexpiry":"11738.63"},{"cdexpiry":"v120","vlexpiry":"2104.49"},{"cdexpiry":"v175","vlexpiry":"2678.84"},{"cdexpiry":"v220","vlexpiry":"823.44"},{"cdexpiry":"v170","vlexpiry":"17207.36"},{"cdexpiry":"v140","vlexpiry":"6131.73"},{"cdexpiry":"v110","vlexpiry":"1605.88"},{"cdexpiry":"v165","vlexpiry":"19333.84"},{"cdexpiry":"v210","vlexpiry":"3260.41"},{"cdexpiry":"v160","vlexpiry":"19818.10"}],"mode":"0213","change":"N"},{"expiry":{"cdexpiry":"v210","vlexpiry":"296.78"},"mode":"0101","change":"N"},{"expiry":[{"cdexpiry":"v245","vlexpiry":"14495.37"},{"cdexpiry":"v255","vlexpiry":"35462.84"},{"cdexpiry":"v250","vlexpiry":"15679.97"}],"mode":"0217","change":"N"}],"type":"8"}
JSON;

foreach (json_decode($json)->list as $listKey=>$listObj) {
    printf("[%03d] mode: %s / change: %s\n", $listKey, $listObj->mode, $listObj->change);
    if (is_array($listObj->expiry)) {
        foreach ($listObj->expiry as $expKey=>$obj) {
            printf("  [%03d] cdexpiry: %s / vlexpiry: %s\n", 
                   $expKey, $obj->cdexpiry, $obj->vlexpiry);
        }
    } else {
        $obj = $listObj->expiry;
        printf("  cdexpiry: %s / vlexpiry: %s\n", $obj->cdexpiry, $obj->vlexpiry);        
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
[000] mode: 0401 / change: N
  [000] cdexpiry: v130 / vlexpiry: 33528.99
  [001] cdexpiry: v230 / vlexpiry: 21648.39
  [002] cdexpiry: v150 / vlexpiry: 185350.30
  [003] cdexpiry: v120 / vlexpiry: 33904.03
  [004] cdexpiry: v175 / vlexpiry: 47796.73
  [005] cdexpiry: v220 / vlexpiry: 21258.62
  [006] cdexpiry: v170 / vlexpiry: 261294.42
  [007] cdexpiry: v140 / vlexpiry: 98363.25
  [008] cdexpiry: v110 / vlexpiry: 30818.43
  [009] cdexpiry: v165 / vlexpiry: 298457.07
  [010] cdexpiry: v240 / vlexpiry: 13807.67
  [011] cdexpiry: v210 / vlexpiry: 10761.00
  [012] cdexpiry: v160 / vlexpiry: 321684.92
[001] mode: 0204 / change: N
  cdexpiry: v210 / vlexpiry: 3501.37
[002] mode: 1904 / change: N
  cdexpiry: v40 / vlexpiry: 1091.46
[003] mode: 0213 / change: N
  [000] cdexpiry: v130 / vlexpiry: 2084.08
  [001] cdexpiry: v260 / vlexpiry: 28362.31
  [002] cdexpiry: v230 / vlexpiry: 823.44
  [003] cdexpiry: v150 / vlexpiry: 11738.63
  [004] cdexpiry: v120 / vlexpiry: 2104.49
  [005] cdexpiry: v175 / vlexpiry: 2678.84
  [006] cdexpiry: v220 / vlexpiry: 823.44
  [007] cdexpiry: v170 / vlexpiry: 17207.36
  [008] cdexpiry: v140 / vlexpiry: 6131.73
  [009] cdexpiry: v110 / vlexpiry: 1605.88
  [010] cdexpiry: v165 / vlexpiry: 19333.84
  [011] cdexpiry: v210 / vlexpiry: 3260.41
  [012] cdexpiry: v160 / vlexpiry: 19818.10
[004] mode: 0101 / change: N
  cdexpiry: v210 / vlexpiry: 296.78
[005] mode: 0217 / change: N
  [000] cdexpiry: v245 / vlexpiry: 14495.37
  [001] cdexpiry: v255 / vlexpiry: 35462.84
  [002] cdexpiry: v250 / vlexpiry: 15679.97
```

Considering that strange structure of the JSON data you receive I really would recommend to try to have that structure fixed insteead of trying to use that structure. The unexpected varying formatting inside the JSON data makes it unnecessarily complex to process. I fail to see a reason for that. objects inside an API response should *always* have a strict and uniform structure.

Comment: This is the original query return file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1odW2Ctt5d3Z_07VoWkiE2_ltscP7_vRi/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: That actually is a _different_ structure, if you look closely. One that actually _does_ make sense.